# pyspark toPandas Error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a messy and very big data set consisting of Chinese characters, numbers, strings, date.etc. After I did some cleaning using pyspark and want to turn it into a pandas, it raises this error:
    `IOPub data rate exceeded.
    The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
    to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
    To change this limit, set the config variable
    --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit.
17/06/06 18:48:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 393, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)`

And above the error, it outputs some of my original data.It's very long. So I just post part of it.
[image]

I have checked my cleaned data. All column type are `int`, `double`. Why does it still output my old data?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching jupyter notebook increasing 'iopub_data_rate_limit' as:

jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000

Source: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2287

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to put this in your jupyterhub_config.py file:

`c.Spawner.args = ['--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000000']`